# how can i use sql server 2008 in symfony2?

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, symfony

hi i installed sqlsrv drive in my php/ext/ and i use php 5.4.16 and i use sql server 2008 in my laptop but when i execute the symfony2 commande ***doctrine:mapping:import" AssuranceCarteBundle"*** an error is displayed and this is the error text :

[PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[IMSSP]: This extension requires the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native
  Client ODBC Driver to communicate with SQL Server. Access the following
  URL to download the Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Native Client ODBC driver for
   x86: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=163712

I don't know why he said this because I don't use  sqlserver 2012 and i need to use sql server 2008 how can i resolve this problem please?!
thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The configuration of database driver should be placed in `parameters.yml`, if the driver is available.